# Group law derived from lie group homomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\to G$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $f: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G$ be any smooth map such that $f(0)=1, f_{*}(0)=\mathrm{id}$. Such a map proffers a local coordinate system near $1 \in G $ and there exists some bilinear map $B: \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ such that $f(x) f(y)=f(x+y+B(x, y)+\ldots)$. Then we desire to prove $B(x, y)-B(y, x)=[x, y]$.

It's the exercise $3.2$ in Kirillov's [*An Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ekirillov/liegroups/liegroups.pdf). I fail to conjure up a path to connect $f$ with Lie bracket or exponential map.

Hope for an answer!

Comment: See page $51$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjuq5SnuqvxAhXNm6QKHTzGABYQFjAJegQIEBAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fir.cwi.nl%2Fpub%2F2517%2F2517D.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0wE9zmmNZOLvK9P6prsREo).

Comment: Thanks for the reference!